# Is there a graceful way to preserve interrupt status when it's reset by private source code?

Tags: java, awt, interrupt, awtrobot

I'm using the Robot class to perform mouse functions in my program, however I've encountered an issue with it swallowing the InterruptedException and printing the stack trace. This is not good because I need the interrupted status to be preserved.

I've found the issue occurs specifically in the delay() function of the Robot class, which is called internally:

```
public synchronized void delay(int ms) {
    checkDelayArgument(ms);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(ms);
    } catch (InterruptedException ite) {
        ite.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The function is public so I was able to create a custom class that extends Robot and override this method to include `Thread.currentThread.interrupt();` in the catch block, however I consider this a nasty hack which may have repercussions. Is there a better way to handle this issue?

Comment: It's not a nasty hack to extend something like that: it's literally how the language works.

Comment: @MadPhysicist 
That's not the point. Why would the source code just swallow the exception like that? There must be some reason but I don't know what it is and that bugs me.

Comment: Both questions are opinion based. The developers had to do *something*, so they did. Unless you find one of the original devs here, I doubt you're going to get an overwhelmingly convincing answer that explains what they were thinking at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like this [JDK bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8210231) and note these dev mail  [comments here](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/awt-dev/2019-December/015630.html).

If you view JDK17 source code you'll see a different implementation which does not lose the status of the interrupt, though because of backward compatibility the original `InterruptedException` is lost:

```
public void delay(int ms) {
    checkDelayArgument(ms);
    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
    if (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (final InterruptedException ignored) {
            thread.interrupt(); // Preserve interrupt status
        }
    }
}
```

If you are not able to update to a later JDK it looks like you may as well call `Thread.sleep(ms);` and handle the exception in your own code.